# Getting error using access database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access-2007

Code modification SQL to MS access database.
This is my working code using SQL database and want to change ms access database but getting an error. Below working code using sql database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 BindData();
}


private void BindData()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mazhar-PC;Initial Catalog=MKE;user id=sa;password=ok; ");
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_GetProductsForCategories", myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    // Attach the relationship to the dataSet
    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("CategoriesRelation", ds.Tables[0].Columns["CategoryID"],
    ds.Tables[1].Columns["CategoryID"]));
    outerRep.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    outerRep.DataBind();

}


protected void outerRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        Repeater innerRep = e.Item.FindControl("innerRep") as Repeater;
        innerRep.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("CategoriesRelation");
        innerRep.DataBind();

    }
}
```

I used two tables:

```
Category
Product
```

Category table has been following columns:

CategoryID
CategoryName

Product table has been following columns:

PID
ImageName
ProductName
Price
CategoryID

I have a stored procedure in sql to get results according to category and their products.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetProductsForCategories]
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Category 
    WHERE CategoryID IN (SELECT CategoryID FROM Product) SELECT p.PID, p.ImageName, p.ProductName, p.Price, p.CategoryID FROM Product p
```

Below not working code using ms access database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 BindData();
}


private void BindData()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\LKKT1\My Documents\Downloads\examples\demo1\kkk.accdb";
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "create procedure usp_GetProductsForCategories as select * from Category3 where CategoryID IN (select CategoryID from Product3) SELECT p.PID, p.ImageName, p.ProductName, p.Price, p.CategoryID FROM Product3 p
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter ad=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("CategoriesRelation",ds.Tables[0].Columns["CategoryID"],
    ds.Tables[1].Columns["CategoryID"]));
    outerRep.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
    outerRep.DataBind();
 }


protected void outerRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        Repeater innerRep = e.Item.FindControl("innerRep") as Repeater;
        innerRep.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("CategoriesRelation");
        innerRep.DataBind();

    }
}
```

I am using a nested repeater to display product according to category. Its giving error on dataset filling time.

Comment: Below is a link of my error: http://postimg.org/image/sp9ajzfxh/

Comment: @user3793996 please look at the inner exception, what does it say?

Comment: Yes, I am confused whether written correct stored procedure or not. And I don't have idea of inner exception. Can you write code for BindData method. 3dd

Comment: On the image you sent, when the error occurs, click the view details button. Then view the exception and then the inner exception. The reason for the error should be in there

Comment: Yea, I am displaying product images with the price in my app but still confused, can you write the code for BindData.

Comment: This is t-sql, what has MS Access got to do with it?

Comment: Yes. The problem with stored procedure only no one giving proper result. Remou

Comment: You are using SQL server code, not MS Access code. Are you sure that your database is ms Access? You have `dbo.` which is SQL Server. Please use @ when talking to people eg @Remou

Comment: I am using ms access database with have two tables in that Category3 and Product3 and can you write BindData method. I have not been getting since two days. @Remou

Comment: In MS Access you create a procedure like so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861(v=office.15).aspx, however, you would be much better off just storing a query and referring to that. Command type would then be stored procedure and command text the query name. Just get the query working in MS Access and move on from there.

Comment: Can you write the query for the above stored procedure. I am still confused. @Remou

Comment: No, I will not. There is a query design window in MS Access, try it.

Comment: I did, but according to my query its given confusing to me. Please @Remou

Comment: What is the sql of the query you tried?

Comment: SELECT * FROM Category WHERE CategoryID IN (SELECT CategoryID FROM Product) SELECT p.PID, p.ImageName, p.ProductName, p.Price, p.CategoryID FROM Product p

Comment: That is not valid MS Access SQL. Use the query design window to add tables and joins. You must say @ every time if you wish me to be notified.

Comment: Please notify you only. I don't know how to join two tables in ms access. @Remou

Comment: There is a lot of help for MS Acccess eg http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-in-a-query-mdb-HP005188003.aspx

Comment: I am getting lots of examples, but I am not unable to implement my query that is my problem. @Remou

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you? You understand that stackoverflow is about help, not writing code?

Comment: Actually, not good in database, I am not asking code, just one query. @Remou

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "select * from Category3 
where CategoryID IN (select CategoryID from Product3) SELECT p.PID, p.ImageName, 
p.ProductName, p.Price, p.CategoryID FROM Product3 p";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter ad=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
```

You appear to be creating a stored procedure and trying to fill a dataset with it each time you bind the data.

Comment: This code is same as my above code, then what is my mistake.

Comment: Yes, that is my point. Why are you creating a stored procedure each time?

Comment: I want to display product with images according to category wise and I used nested repeater for display product and category. And admin can add many categories and their products. The above SQL code is working perfectly, but the requirement is access database.

Comment: remove the "create procedure usp_GetProductsForCategories as" code and it might work. My point is that you do not want to create a stored procedure in this code.

Comment: I had implemented code according to this example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/showing-category-and-subcategory-using-nested-repeater-in-as/

Comment: No, you haven't. For the last time, you are creating an SP on each call to binditem where you should not be.

Comment: After removing of "create procedure usp_GetProductsForCategories as" code and again error showing like that: Syntax error in query expression 'CategoryID IN (select CategoryID from Product3) select p.PID,p.ImageName,p.Price,p.CategoryID from Product3 p'.

Comment: Yes. I need same result as above are implemented example link which shown above. How to write stored procedure using access database. In access I created two table product and category.

Comment: @ChrisBint That SQL is not valid for MS Access